# conditionally required field if another field has a value using array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I want to make one field required, but only if the first field has some value on it.

I know I could do something like this, using when if this wasn't an array of objects, but since it is, the validation is not working.

```
myFieldArray: yup.array().of(
  yup.object().shape({
    firstField: yup.string(),
    secondField: yup.string().when("firstField", {
      is: (firstField) => firstField.length > 0,
      then: yup.string().required("this field is required"),
    }),
  })
)
```

I tried to use yup.ref too, but "when" don't accept refs, only strings

```
myFieldArray: yup.array().of(
  yup.object().shape({
    firstField: yup.string(),
    secondField: yup.string().when(yup.ref("firstField"), {
      is: (firstField) => firstField.length > 0,
      then: yup.string().required("this field is required"),
    }),
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked

```
myArray: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
        firstField: Yup.string(),
        secondField: Yup.string().when("firstField", {
            is: firstField => firstField && firstField.length > 0,
            then: Yup.string().required("this field is required")
        })
    })
)
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-yup-forked-wcfkh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Sku, check this out !!

Comment: I don't know if the problem is the react-hook-form, this actually doens't work with it

Comment: I see. If I have time I will check the same in react-hooks-form as well